# UI Actionscript Framework ... Can't find!

Tags: actionscript-3

Some time ago i found an actionscript user interface framework on the web that emulates android and ios ui's ... now i cant' find it, do you have any ideia where i can get it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not a framework, but a component set I found for android: http://xperiments.es/blog/en/as3-android-flash-components/ and a similar one: https://github.com/bustardcelly/as3flobile-android. is this the kind of thing you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Flexoid components set to use with Flex http://code.google.com/p/flexoid/